# Let $Q$ and $P$ be $n\times n$ matrix, then $PQ$ and $QP$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is the following statement true ?

> Let $Q$ and $P$ be $n\times n$ matrix, then $PQ$ and $QP$ have the same eigenvalues.

What if $Q$ is invertible ?

**Edit:**

We do not assume that $P$ and $Q$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus This assumes $P$ and $Q$ have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes I changed it just now. But still this counts as a counterexample

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus But in quantum mechanics, we deal with infinite dimensional vector spaces, and we are talking finite dimensional vector spaces here.

Comment: @saulspatz No we do not assume such thing.

Comment: Not necessarily. Spin for example is finite dimensional.

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector of $PQ$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $Qv\neq0$, then $Qv$ is easily seen to be an eigenvector of $QP$ with $\lambda$ as eigenvalue.

Comment: @Arthur How ? we apparently couldn't see that, so I would appreciate if you could write it explicitly.

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus Then give me a specific counterexample, and don't say just "there are some counterexamples."

Comment: It's a straight-forward calculation:$$QP(Qv)=Q(PQv)=Q(\lambda v)=\lambda Qv$$

Comment: No additional assumptions on the underlying field?

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus It is the field of real numbers.

Comment: @Arthur And how does help us to show the statement in the question ? I'm little confused.

Comment: @onurcanbektas The field doesn't matter.  Arthur's argument is valid over any field.

Comment: @saulspatz see my last comment

Comment: @Arthur And if $Qv=0,$ then $\lambda=0,$ so at least one of $P,Q$ is singular, and then $QP$ is singular and has a zero eigenvalue.  Thus, the matrices have the same eigenvalues.  What does invertibility of $Q$ have to do with it?

Comment: @saulspatz if $Qv$ is zero, why do we need $\lambda = 0 $ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Arthur has shown that an eigenvalue of $PQ$ is an eigenvalue of $QP$ except in the case that $Qv=0$.  I was simply filling in that case.  $\lambda v = P(Qv) = P0 = 0.$  Now $v$ is an eigenvector so $v \ne 0$ so we must have $\lambda = 0.$

Comment: @Arthur If the $Q$ is not invertible, that proof does not work, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Q$ is an invertible matrix, then $PQ$ and $QP$ are in fact *similar* matrices. This is easy to see : $Q^{-1}(QP)Q = PQ$. Therefore, it obviously is the case that $QP$ and $PQ$ have the same eigenvalues, in fact up to multiplicity. (I leave you to see this yourself. Use arguments illustrated in the comments above).

Now, let $P$ and $Q$ not be invertible. We'll assume they are over the real numbers. Thanks to $GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$ being dense in $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$, we have that there exist invertible matrices $Q_n \to Q$ (entrywise convergence). Since right and left matrix multiplication are both continuous operations, we see that $PQ_n \to PQ$ and $Q_nP \to QP$. Now, $Q_nP$ and $PQ_n$ have the same eigenvalues up to multiplicity, and therefore the same characteristic polynomial.

The characteristic polynomial of any matrix $A$ has coefficients which are polynomials in the entries of $A$. Therefore, if $A_n \to A$, then it also follows by continuity of polynomials that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomials of $A_n$ converges to the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

The above argument shows that the characteristic polynomial of $PQ$ is the limit of the characteristic polynomials of $PQ_n$, and similarly for $QP$ and $Q_nP$. But then $Q_nP$ and $PQ_n$ have the same characteristic polynomial, hence $PQ$ and $QP$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

> In particular, for $P,Q \in M_{n \times n}$, $PQ$ and $QP$ have the same eigenvalues, up to multiplicity as well.

However, if $P \in M_{m \times n}$ and  $Q \in M_{n \times m}$, then too $PQ$ and $QP$ are square matrices, then too you can ask about their eigenvalues. Of course, a similar argument to what we did above doesn't hold(since the concept of inverses will be defenestrated), but the result is still stunning : $\chi_{PQ}(t) = \chi_{QP}(t) \times t^{m-n}$, where $m>n$. Therefore, the non-zero eigenvalues of $PQ$ still equal those of $QP$ up to multiplicity, but what can at most occur beyond that is one having the zero eigenvalue and the other not having it. The proof of this can be given neatly using block matrices, and I can append it if you request.